# Clear an IKImageView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, ikimageview

I have an IKImageView set up to display in my mac application but when you don't give it an image, its starts with like a noisy broken screenshot of my own desktop rather than being empty. How can I simply clear it and have it empty?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only display it IF you actually have an image. If you don't have one just show the user a label or something saying 'No Image' or similar.